# Illegal instruction on execution

Tags: coredump, sycl, illegal-instruction

I'm trying to install hipSYCL on Nvidia GPU, hipSYCL is installed but it is giving illegal instruction error when try to run the `syclcc` compiler.

I tried running `syclcc` command on CPU and here is its output:

```
$ syclcc --version --opensycl-targets="cuda:sm_80"
clang version 16.0.0
Target: aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/bhoomikahn/llvm-project-llvmorg-16.0.0/build/bin
```

But when I try it on GPU:

```
$ syclcc --version --opensycl-targets="cuda:sm_80"
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I have no idea what's happening, any suggestions would be appreciated
thank you.

Comment: Hi, syclcc is just a python script. Likely either python or clang/LLVM is not compiled for the target you are executing the code on. Can you provide some details on how you have installed the stack, and what system you are running on?

Comment: @illuhad I built opensycl on nvidia gpu(ampere architecture)having centos linux using the command "cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/bhoomikahn/llvm-project-llvmorg-16.0.0/build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;openmp;ldd" -DLLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB=ON -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="AArch64;NVPTX" -S /home/bhoomikahn/llvm-project-llvmorg-16.0.0/llvm"

Comment: What do you mean by "I try it on GPU"? I guess you mean a GPU node? Could it be that the GPU node has a different CPU than the node that you used for building hipSYCL?

Comment: Please don't add critical information in the comments. You can edit your question and add the information there.